# dwmapi.lib, D3DCompiler.lib, and Comctl32.lib gives linker warning about d3d11.lib

Tags: c++

Specifically, the warnings are:

```
4>Comctl32.lib(COMCTL32.dll) : warning LNK4006: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in d3d11.lib(d3d11.dll); second definition ignored
4>D3DCompiler.lib(D3DCOMPILER_47.dll) : warning LNK4006: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in d3d11.lib(d3d11.dll); second definition ignored
4>dwmapi.lib(dwmapi.dll) : warning LNK4006: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in d3d11.lib(d3d11.dll); second definition ignored
```

From what I have read online this means I have linked `d3d11.lib` more than once.

What I am doing is I am linking `Comctl32.lib` `D3DCompiler.lib` `d3d11.lib` and `dwmapi.lib` to a static library, and then linking that static library (and nothing else) in another executable. The warning only occurs when building the static library and it does not occur when building the executable. I know that this would probably not affect anything, but it is good to just get rid of all warnings.

I am using Visual Studio with solutions generated by Premake. There shouldn't be anything in the Premake side of things that change things because the aforementioned libs are just listed in the Additional Dependencies field of the property pages. I have checked that I have not listed anything in the Additional Dependencies field of the executable.

I know that I probably did not include as much information as needed to definitively solve the problem, but any tips to point me to the right direction will be great. Thank you!

Comment: It is not possible to link anything to static library.

Comment: @user7860670 I know that it is not possible to link anything to a static library, but in Visual Studio it is "possible". From my understanding what it does is when an executable or a dll links the static library, it also links all the dependencies from the static library.

Answer (score 3):

Although *Microsoft Visual Studio* allows a static library to be linked to other static libraries via the **Librarian** property pages, **LNK4006** errors are inevitable when you do this.

The *correct* way to do it is to first remove all **Additional Dependencies** from the static library's **Librarian** properties. Instead, add the following pragmas to your static library's "public" header file:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"d3dcompiler.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"dwmapi.lib")
```

Compile your static library for each configuration and platform.

In your executable project properties:

**C/C++ - General - Additional Include Directories**

- Add your static library folder (the folder containing your "public" header file).

**Linker - General - Additional Library Directories**

- Add your static library folder.

**Linker - Input - Additional Dependencies**

- Add your static library (lib) file.

You can now compile your project without **LNK4006** warnings.

Note: the **Linker** properties must be repeated for each configuration and platform.